# Split Screen percentual and with dp

Tags: android, android-layout

I got the following problem, I would like to split my screen in 2 Parts, a top navigation bar, wether action nor toolbar are an option in this case for more complex reasons, setting the navigation bar as % is also rather difficult since a percentage value differs from absolute size on different devices(Phone/Pad).

The navigation bar part should be 100dp and I am looking for a way to use the rest of my screen as a new 100% for a `RelativeLayout` so that when i use `fill_parent` the white part as seen below would equal to those 100%.

If possible an axml solution would be prefferably so everything that is C# or Java based is an Option but a bad one.

[image: Example]

I tried to just do the following, but i believe it just corretly sets the size to the full parent object, i cant figure out how to solve this.

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#f0f0f0" >

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#ffffff">    
<!--Some Content-->  
</LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">    
   <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
        app:layout_heightPercent="100%"
        android:background="#ffffff">
   <!--Some Content-->  
 </RelativeLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try to use `android:layout_weight`

Comment: How especially? If i recall correctly that would give a percentage based weight to both parts, but only one part of those regions can be percentage based. Would you mind giving an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confusion is a result of using percentage values on a `PercentRelativeLayout` itself: you may use those only on its children. In the following example you still have a 100dp toolbar and a `RelativeLayout` that is placed directly below it while taking all the free space. All the children of this layout will be measured relatively to this `PercentRelativeLayout`, and not to a whole screen.

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#f0f0f0" >

    <LinearLayout 
                android:id="@+id/toolBarLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="#ffffff">    
    <!--Some Content-->  
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
            android:layout_below="@id/toolBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ffffff">

            <!-- all the content here may be measured relatively to
            a parent PercentRelativeLayout -->

            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    app:layout_heightPercent="50%"/>

    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Im in a meeting , i will give you feedback tomorrow when i have time to try this out.

Answer (score 0):

Like Below you can split screen.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/layoutfifth">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Text 1"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Text 2"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">



             <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Text 3"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Text 4"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />



        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```